# How do I combine accel key in Gtk?

Tags: c, gtk

Here's the function I use to add an accelerator (hotkey) to a closure (function)

```
void
gtk_accel_group_connect (GtkAccelGroup *accel_group,
                         guint accel_key,
                         GdkModifierType accel_mods,
                         GtkAccelFlags accel_flags,
                         GClosure *closure);
```

`accel_key` is the value of the key we want to activate the function, here's we have keys: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h

How can I combine keys, for example `GDK_KEY_Control_L` and `GDK_KEY_s` to set the save function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [gtk_accelerator_parse](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accelerator-parse)

```
guint key;
GdkModifierType mod;
gtk_accelerator_parse("<Ctrl>s", &key, &mod);
```

The returned `key` will be your `accel_key`

Side note: the linked header must define all those values as `unsigned`....